# Show pause/play icons when hover/mouseenter over video

Tags: jquery, video

So this code works as expected. Hover/mouseenter/mouseleave shows and displays the pause/play icons correctly.

The issue I have is on page load the pause icon doesn't show on Hover/mouseenter? It only works after first click... Any help appreciated, thank you.

```
// HTML
<div class="video-container">
  <div class="video-controls"> </div>
  <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="img/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
// END HTML

// jQuery
// Show video Play/Pause icons
$("#myVideo").mouseenter(function() {
    $('.video-controls').show();
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $('.video-controls').hide();
});


// Pause/Play video on hover
$("#myVideo").bind("click", function () {
  var vid = $(this).get(0);
      if (vid.paused) {
        vid.play();
        $('.video-controls').html('<i class="fas fa-pause-circle pause"></i>');
      } else {
        vid.pause();
        $('.video-controls').html('<i class="fas fa-play-circle play"></i>');
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank your question,

here is the solution try out once

```
// HTML
<div class="video-container">
  <div class="video-controls"><i class="fas fa-pause-circle play"></i></div>
  <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="img/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
// END HTML

// jQuery
// Show video Play/Pause icons
$("#myVideo").mouseenter(function() {
    $('.video-controls').show();
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $('.video-controls').hide();
});


// Pause/Play video on hover
$("#myVideo").bind("click", function () {
  var vid = $(this).get(0);
      if (vid.paused) {
        vid.play();
        $('.video-controls').html('<i class="fas fa-pause-circle pause"></i>');
      } else {
        vid.pause();
        $('.video-controls').html('<i class="fas fa-play-circle play"></i>');
      }
  });
```

I found that after click event you have binded html so we need default state so just put default video control to play icon.

Hope this will sort your query.

Comment: Of course.. Doh! Thank you very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> *"The issue I have is on page load the pause icon doesn't show on Hover/mouseenter? 
> It only works after first click."*

You can try listening for a **hover** event instead of binding (connecting) to a **click** event:

```
//# Pause/Play video on hover
// $("#myVideo").bind("click", function () {

$("#myVideo").hover(function() {
    var vid = $(this).get(0);
      if (vid.paused) {
        vid.play();
        $('.video-controls').html('<i class="fas fa-pause-circle pause"></i>');
      } else {
        vid.pause();
        $('.video-controls').html('<i class="fas fa-play-circle play"></i>');
      }
  });
```

Comment: Although this works and is a good idea if you want to play/pause only when mouse is hover video, in my case I want the click event. Thank you for taking the time, appreciated.